# I have created a dashboard using a custom app in the rally. For now, I am just copy-pasting my code to it, but I want to do it through GitHub?

Tags: code-rally, rallyapi

I have created a dashboard using a custom app in the rally. For now, I am just copy-pasting my code to it, but I want to do it through GitHub. How can I achieve this?

i want it as i made changes in the code through github and then it should reflect in the rally dashboard custom app